# ¿Como escribo en un archivo/fichero al inicio?

Tags: c++, archivo, almacenamiento

Estoy haciendo un programa en el cual necesito 2 opciones, una de insertar al inicio y otra de insertar al final, ya se como insertarlo al final lo cual es añadiendo la bandera "app" y el cursor se va escribir al final del archivo, mi duda es ¿con cual bandera puedo poner el cursor al incio del archivo para que escriba al inicio?.

Ya he buscado en muchos sitios web pero no lo encuentro.

El código que estoy empleando es el siguiente:

```
ofstream fout(ruta, ios::app);

if(!fout.good()){
    cout<<"Error al arbir el archivo txt"<<endl;
}

fout.write((char*)&objA, sizeof (A));

fout.close();
```

Comment: Escribir al inicio ... ¿ Sobreescribiendo el contenido previo, o insertandolo al principio (de forma que el archivo resultante sea mas grande que el original) ?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la segunda opción, necesito añadir sin que se borre lo que ya tenia anteriormente en el archivo...

Comment: Tienes que reescribir el archivo entero, copia el archivo a otro temporal, añade los contenidos a uno nuevo, y luego restaura lo que había en el temporal al final de el nuevo. No hay otra manera de hacerlo porque, al menos en los sistemas de archivos convencionales, accedes con un puntero al fichero, que se mueve por las posiciones de memoria que ocupa el mismo, reemplazando lo que se encuentre a su paso, por lo que, lo que te queda como opción es tener una copia con los otros datos del fichero.